In a react typescript code, i am getting ts 2322
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

const CustomTextField = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
    padding: '8px',
  },
}));

const MyComponent = () => (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DatePicker
            format='MM/DD/YYYY'
            renderInput={(params: TextFieldProps) => <CustomTextField {...params} />}
        />
    </LocalizationProvider>
);

This is my code.
I'm getting the below error in renderInput line.

Type '{ format: string; renderInput: (params: TextFieldProps) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<Dayjs, false> & RefAttributes'.
Property 'renderInput' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<Dayjs, false> & RefAttributes'.ts(2322)

Please help me to resolve it
Why is this error coming and how to solve it?

renderInput is not present in MUI API since v5: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/
You have to use textField from Slots https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#slots. For example:
<DatePicker
  {...props}
  slots={{
    textField: params => <CustomTextField {...params} />
  }}
/>


Glad to be helpful. Have a nice day
